# How can I use schema markup for multiple video reviews on one page

Tags: schema.org

On my page I aggregate products reviews:

- URLs to pages with reviews (with overview)
- URLs to videos (with player)

How can I use schema markup for multiple product reviews like this?

I read all the topics regarding multiple schema here (that is how I got here) but unfortunately cound’t find the right „recipe”.

Different from my side:

- reviews and videos are external (linked)
- I do only preview, sometimes ratings (from their schema)

Comment: We have quite a few questions here already related to using [multiple schema](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=multiple+schema+is%3Aq) on one page. If those don't answer your question, please edit your question to provide more details and it will be added to our review queue automatically.

Comment: @dan OK so let me be more clear: https://productz.com/en/apple-airpods-max/p/9GoME Has 41 reviews and 7 video reviews (+users rating - stars for schema). How to wrap everything? o.O

Comment: We really don't give "recipes" here or do individual SEO reviews as those would [only apply to your site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You might start with the linked question for multiple reviews on one page, and then add schema for the videos. You can test your schema markup using Google's testing tools [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data). If you need help with specific schema markup, then please add that to another question and we'll see if we can help.